# Terraform - A managed resource has not been declared in the root module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

i'm trying create ec2 instance and setup load balancer using terraform but i'm facing follwing error. How to create instance and configure load balacer in a single main.tf file?

> Error: Reference to undeclared resource
>
> "aws_lb_target_group" "front-end":27:   vpc_id   = "${aws_vpc.terrafom-elb.id}"
> A managed resource "aws_vpc" "terrafom-elb" has not been declared in the root
> module.source`

code:

```
  region = "us-east-1"
  access_key = "*********************"
  secret_key = "**********************"
}

resource "aws_instance" "terraform" {
  ami           = "ami-07ebfd5b3428b6f4d"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  security_groups    = ["nodejs","default"]
  tags = {
    Name = "terrafom-elb"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb" "front-end"{
  name = "front-end-lb"
  internal = false
  security_groups    = ["nodejs"]

}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "front-end" {
  name     = "front-end"
  port     = 8989
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id   = "${aws_vpc.terrafom-elb.id}"
  depends_on = [aws_instance.terraform]
}
```

Comment: There is indeed no `aws_vpc` resource in this config. Can you share the rest of your config that contains it?

Comment: or maybe is it a data source that you want to use ? in that case you may use data.aws_vpc.terraform_elb instead.

if not, Matt is right, the rest of the config is needed to understand the issue

Comment: "r" is missing in vpc_id   = "${aws_vpc.terrafom-elb.id}"

Comment: Make sure all the modified file changes are saved before you run the plan command

Answer (score 12):

You can add a `data` structure to the top and pass VPC ID as variable:

```
data "aws_vpc" "selected" {
  id = var.vpc_id
}
```

And reference it as `vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.selected.id`

Answer (score 12):

There's a typo where you're assigning the vpc_id:

```
vpc_id   = "${aws_vpc.terrafom-elb.id}"
```

should be:

```
vpc_id   = "${aws_vpc.terraform-elb.id}"
```

note the missing 'r' in the word 'terraform'